# Azure AD B2C associate user flow with an app one-to-one

Tags: azure, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

While researching how to require multi-factor auth for a specific app, I came across this challenge:

- It's possible to create User flows (policies) in Azure AD B2C that would either require MFA or not
- It's possible to use any of the user flows in any application. Selecting the user flow is done client-side in the provided samples, so it would be relatively easy to go around the MFA requirement by just using a suitable user flow. This can be guessed or found in another app.

**Is there a way to require an app to use a specific user flow or restrict a user flow to be used with specific apps?**

*More information:*

- Use a specific user Flow in an application:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-spa
- Code sample:
  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp
- User flows in Azure B2C:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies

Answer (score 2):

In Azure AD B2C, you aren't able to constrain an app to a flow or vice versa, however a given app can ensure that a specific flow was executed by validating [the `tfp` claim in the ID token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens#claims) that is issued to it.

The `tfp` claim is set to the name of the policy (e.g. `b2c_1_signupsignin1`) that was executed to acquire the ID token.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Chris! Another sample I've received earlier is https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite. Storing secrets in the SPAs and mobile apps could be challenging, and I'm hoping the ability to constrain apps/flows feature will be added to AD B2C.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs this today, it's achievable with [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) by  overriding JwtIssuer technical profile and adding a metadata item for ["IssuanceClaimPattern"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/jwt-issuer-technical-profile) .